# adding additional css classes have no effect within block editor

Tags: css, block-editor, theme-customizer

I've been inserting CSS through the `Customizer -> Additional CSS`. Then I will add some classes within the block editor to single blocks, using the `Advanced -> additional css classes` field

My main issue is that such CSS classes have no effect whatsoever within the Block Editor: I will see any effects only if I create a preview of a page. This makes any editing quite cumbersome.

I've also tried to insert the css using the theme file editor instead of the customizer (through `Appearance -> Theme File Editor`), but such css actually will not apply at all, might be an issue of the theme I use.

What is the best way to add CSS which will be applied already within the block editor, without need to use the preview?

Comment: You can use `add_editor_style()` or the [`enqueue_block_editor_assets` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_editor_assets/). See [this comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/#comment-5332), [this article](https://rudrastyh.com/gutenberg/css.html) and maybe also https://wordpress.org/support/topic/applying-styles-to-gutenberg-block-editor/

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you. I'll try this, it looks promising.